# Help us close duplicates of two new Community FAQ questions

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, vote-to-close, community-faq

I've recently added two questions to the Community FAQ because they were found to have many duplicates:

- [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem)
- [My keyboard is typing by itself, could there be a ghost in it?](https://superuser.com/questions/441608/my-keyboard-is-typing-by-itself-could-there-be-a-ghost-in-it)

Please help us tidy up Super User by voting to close any open questions listed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/linked/871850) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/linked/441608) as duplicates where appropriate. If you find any other duplicates, be sure to vote to close them, too. Thanks!

Comment: Where's the community FAQ?

Comment: @Raystafarian: [tag:community-faq]